# Initial job has not accepted any resources in AWS EMR

Tags: apache-spark

I have an EMR cluster in AWS.

I am building a RStudio Server to use that cluster.

I am able to get a spark-shell and execute `spark.sql("show tables").show` and see the tables in HDFS from the server that is running RStudio.

However if I execute  `spark.sql("select * from ny_taxi_hdfs limit 10").show` it fails with the error.
 Initial job has not accepted any resources.

If I do the same thing from the master it works fine.

It does look like it is using yarn "(master = yarn, app id = application_1568817071939_0034)"

Not even sure where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Firewall/Security Groups. Once I opened it up everything worked.
I hate when I ask a question and a day later answer it.